# Is there any benefit to using View in Java code when using findViewById from an XML ImageView?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm writing code where in XML I'm using ImageViews and occasionally TextViews to act as buttons.  I don't need to do anything with them other than setOnClickListeners in my Java code, so I'm wondering if there's any benefit to leaving them as View objects in Java as opposed to casting them to ImageView or TextView objects.

```
 private ImageView mPlayButton;

 mPlayButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
 mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Audio Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 });
```

as opposed to

```
private View mCurrentSongButton;

mCurrentSongButton = findViewById(R.id.currentSongIcon);
mCurrentSongButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SongInfo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Explicit casting will free the interpreter from having to do that itself. Therefore, there's a minimal speed improvement.

Comment: Ok cool, that's what I was wondering.  I guess it's probably not enough to be of a noticeable difference.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to cast a `View` to an `ImageView` just to set `OnClickListener`. Casting an object into a different class doesn't change the object's class i.e an `ImageView` object will remain an `ImageView` when cast as a `View` or even as an `Object`. And thus same methods would be called regardless the reference wrapper of the object itself.

Purpose of casting any object to a child class should only be to *unlock* the otherwise unavailable methods. So if you need to call any methods which are dedicated for an `ImageView`, you will need to cast it to an `ImageView` before hand (but only so you'd be able to `call or use` the method).

In short if there is no need to call a child specific method then don't cast the object, it is simply an overhead for the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your time!  I understand the method access but was more wondering about performance or memory savings or things like that from not casting as ImageView since I don't need any ImageView methods.

Comment: @AaronMonteabaro The only overhead is in performance as mentioned in the answer. Where there is a cost for 'casting' an object. There is no additional overhead memory-wise since no additional object/reference is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to set click listener, then view type is enough but if you need specialized operations like setText(), setEnabled() etc, then you need to cast them